# CSS transition fails when class of sticky element changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, sticky

I want to do a transition when the element gets sticky. But it can't be done with this below code.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.contents');
const initalPos = content.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if(content.offsetTop > initalPos) {
    content.classList.add('stuck');
  } else {
    content.classList.remove('stuck');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.contents {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition: height 3s;
}

.stuck {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
</div>
```

I think apply the CSS transition correctly, what did I miss?

Comment: you have added .stuck {  height: 100px; } css that might be issue

Comment: @Dakshank No, the height `100px` is used for detecting when the element gets sticky.

Comment: is not that animation breaks is that is not happening because it doesn't have any height on the `contents` class

Comment: You can't animate between an auto and fixed height using css. Give the unstuck state a fixed height and it will animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta have an initial fixed height for the transition to work, yet if you don't want this, you can set it programmatically after it's been calculated like this

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.contents');
const initalPos = content.offsetTop;
content.style.height = content.clientHeight + 'px';

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  content.classList.toggle('stuck', content.offsetTop > initalPos);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.contents {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition: height 3s;
}

.stuck {
  height: 100px !important;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So Height does not animate as others styles. To animate height you need to have a starting and ending reference. So that i have added min-height to get actual height animation.

You can give height but that has to be actual height of the element. So there are chances that content will get overflow while adding fixed height.

```js
const content = document.querySelector('.contents');
const initalPos = content.offsetTop;

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if(content.offsetTop > initalPos) {
    content.classList.add('stuck');
  } else {
    content.classList.remove('stuck');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
}

.contents {
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 50px; /* keep as low as your element */
  transition: min-height ease 1s;
}

.stuck {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="contents">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
</div>
```